# Objective C - Return instance of child class without knowing what it is

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I have class `RestModel : NSObject` that handles interaction with a Rest API, with the intention being to subclass for each model accessible via the API (e.g., `PageModel : RestModel` or `PhotoModel : RestModel`)

What I want to do is have a generic `forgeFromDictionary` static method which will return an instance of the subclass, but will be the same for each subclass unless there is some custom instantiation involved. So ideally the `forgeFromDictionary` method would be on my `RestModel`, but I could call `PageModel* myPage = [PageModel forgeFromDictionary:previouslyDefinedDictionary];` and get an actual `PageModel` object.

Is this possible in objective-c?

---

**Here's what I've tried, not sure if I'm on the right track:**

I know I can set the return type of a static method to `instancetype`, which apparently references whichever class is actually calling the method, like so:

`+ (instancetype) forgeFromDictionary: (NSDictionary*) dictionary`

But using `instancetype` anywhere in the actual method gives a fatal error, so this doesn't work:

```
+ (instancetype) forgeFromDictionary: (NSDictionary*) dictionary {
    instancetype *object = [[instancetype alloc] init]; # red alert!
    # "use of undeclared identifier 'instancetype'
    object.properties = dictionary;
    object.original = dictionary;
    return object;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your method, replace:

```
instancetype *object = [[instancetype alloc] init];
```

with:

```
RestModel *object = [[self alloc] init];
```

Comment: Ok great! And then if I want to access methods of a subclass, can I do `PostModel* myPost = (PostModel*) [PostModel forgeFromDictionary:dictionary];`? Or am I overthinking it?

Comment: Yes, except you don't need the cast. Just `PostModel *myPost = [PostModel forgeFromDictionary:dictionary];`

Comment: Ok, so because it returns `instancetype` instead of `RestModel*`, I don't need the cast? If I were to set the return type to `RestModel*` and used the code in your answer, would it also work as long as I casted the return value of `forgeFromDictionary`?

Comment: The problem with that approach is that you need the same method signature in your subclass if you decide to override the factory method, so you end up with a factory method returning a pointer to a superclass, which isn't ideal.

Comment: No problem... Happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the instance class and not the super class maybe you can use something like this:

```
+(id)forgeFromDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dict{
   Class t = [self class];
   id test = [t new];

    // if you have a common property you can set it here by doing
    if([test respondsToSelector:@selector(property)]){
        //set value here
         [test setProperty:val];

    }
    return test;
}
```

using it will just be like:

```
 // you need to cast the object since creating it with id type
 YourClass *instance = (YourClass *)[YourClass forgeFromDictionary:yourDictionary];
```

This will return the instance class and not the super class

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the `new` keyword.